# Rounded corner when change LoadMoreElement background color in Monotouch Dialog

Tags: xamarin.ios, styling, monotouch.dialog

I'm trying using this code :

```
LoadMoreElement elm =  new LoadMoreElement (normalCaption, loadingCaption, tapped);
elm.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue; // new UIColor (27,109,192,1);
elm.TextColor = UIColor.White;
```

This results in a complete blue rectangular cell with no rounded corners.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LoadMoreElement is only intended to be used in the middle of the table, not on the corners.

If you want to use it, you will need to write custom code to render the corners, you can see some sample code in the ImageElements.